# How to set global variable for all controllers in symfony 2?

Tags: symfony

I need a global variable for all the controllers to access into it.Alone with how to use the symfony 2 session variable in all my controllers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basically, what you need is a DI container parameter. In Symfony 2, controllers are always dealing with the container, so you can easily extract such variable into a container parameter.

To do this, you should first define the parameter in your `parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    your_bundle.global_param: 'Hello world'
```

And then, depending on what exactly you need, you can access it differently. When in a controller inherited from Symfony's base controller class, you can fetch the parameter like this:

```
<?php
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

class MyController extends Controller
{
    public function someAction()
    {
        $var = $this->container->getParameter('your_bundle.global_param');
        // $var equals to 'Hello world' now
    }
}
```

On handling session parameters bag, take a look at Symfony's documentation: http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_foundation/sessions.html

Comment: The container parameters are not similar to a variable, they are more like application wide constants, since you are unable to change their value at run-time.

Answer (score 2):

Just in case anyone needs to do the same thing in Symfony3 Framework, it uses ContainerInterface instead of container:

http://api.symfony.com/3.0/Symfony/Component/DependencyInjection/ContainerInterface.html

and you simply would only need to call `getParameter()` (see @kix 's example above) like so:

```
$var = $this->getParameter('your_bundle.global_param');
```

Hopefully this helps someone wanting to do the same thing in Symfony3.